# In graph data structure how can we use intermediate node to calculate distance of any other two nodes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, floyd-warshall

In floyd warshell algorithm we keep any node y as intermediate node and update distance from one node to another(for all nodes) via intermediate node y.
dp[x][y] = min( dp[x][y] , dp[x][z] + dp[z][y])
but the problem here is dp[x][z] may be updated later which means dp[x][z] may not be the minimum distance of reaching x to z, how can we use the dp[x][z] to calculate dp[x][y]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of Floyd--Warshall obscures the mathematical structure of how it works.

The proof would still go through if you updated `dp` in rounds, e.g., for all `x` and `y`, do `dp'[x][y] = min(dp[x][y], min_z(dp[x][z] + dp[z][y]))` and then copy `dp = dp'`. This is enough to ensure that `dp[x][y]` is at most the length of the shortest path from `x` to `y` through the various `z` that we've iterated over so far.

Conversely, we don't end up underestimating `dp[x][y]` by doing in-place updates because every time we do an update, there's a path that achieves the new value (specifically, the path represented by the value of `dp[x][z]` followed by the path represented by the value of `dp[z][y]`).